# How to find out why a Java process died without a trace in Linux

Tags: linux, process

A java process running in our SUSE Linux machine died without leaving a trace as to why it died. If it was killed with kill , it would have been logged and we would have known because the process intercepts that signal. If it crashed, we would have seen a core dump. If it died due to an exception, we would have known due to exception logging. However, the process simply disappeared. I know it was running and then it was not running.

I have checked the bash history of all users, and there is no indication of a `kill -KILL` being performed (this is the only way I can think of that this process can die without a trace).

I suspect that `kill -KILL` or `kill -9` caused the process to die without a trace.

My questions:

1. Is there any way that Linux would kill a process silently?
2. Is there any way to figure out if a process died in the past with a kill -KILL?

Comment: The information on the death of a process is usually only made available to the father process. Do you have a log of what the process was doing when he desappeared?

Comment: Have you checked the system log to see if it was the kernel's OOM killer?

Answer (score 1):

Re (1): A `kill -9 pid` will assasinate the process, without it even getting to say last words. Same for most other uncaught exceptions. Going out of memory can certainly be a reason for a silent death.

Re (2): Unless it's parent notices (calls one of the `wait(3)` family and spills the beans), no. Most of the time long-running processes get reparented to `init(1)` anyway, unless you've got a specially chatty one, it will just silently collect the death certificates and go on with life.

If your system uses [`systemd`](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd), you can set it up to monitor the process closely.